# The method onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I just changed a *ListActivity* to *Activity*, and everything works fine except the code that makes the activity do something if click on List Item (*onListItemClick*).

I get this error:

```
The method onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);

        // Do something

      }
```

( This class was extending ListActivity and everything works fine, but now I want it to extend Activity).

Everything works fine except for this code.

Comment: instead of `onListItemClick` method use `listview.setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: you need to implement `OnItemClickListener` to Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you'd extends as `ListActivity` and after some time you had removed `ListActivity` and extend your class to `Activity`. `onListItemClick` is an override method of `ListActivity` which is not available in `Activity`

Solution : *If you want to use `ListItemClick` in `Activity` so you can do it by following ways else you need to extends your MainClass with `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`*

There are 2 ways to `setOnItemClickListener` to the ListView while using `Activity`

**- Implement `OnItemClickListener` to your `Activity`**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    }
}
```

**- Write `ListView's setOnItemClickListener`**

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have change from `ListActivity` to `Activity` then you have to change `onListItemClick`  to `urListView.setOnItemClickListener` method. Just Like,

```
 urListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        }
    });
```

Comment: I added this and edited it to (ListView l, View v, int position, long id), and still got error

Comment: @SilentKiller Sorry I was posting to the Question Owner.